# How to render an HTMLCollection item?

Tags: javascript

I have the following html:

```html
<div class="avatars">
      <div class="avatar">
        <div>
          <svg data-jdenticon-value="Oamar Kanji"></svg>
        </div>
        <h3 class="name">Oamar Kanji</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="avatar">
        <div>
          <svg data-jdenticon-value="Oamar Kanji"></svg>
        </div>
        <h3 class="name">Jane Doe</h3>
      </div>

</div>
```

I am getting a specific element like so and trying to display it inside another element:

```html
<div id="display-here"/>

    <script>
        let someAvatar = document.getElementsByClassName("avatar").item(0)
        document.getElementById('display-here').innerHTML = someAvatar
    </script>
```

This does not work..

Comment: Render like displaying it as an element?

Comment: Please clarify your question, what do you mean `render`, and how did you try to `render`it

Comment: Yes, I would like to display that element, I have explained further

Comment: If you want to move an element from one location/parent to another you have to use `.appendChild()`

Comment: Is there a way that I can copy the element instead of moving it?

Comment: This blog post might help: https://codeburst.io/learn-how-to-create-html-elements-with-plain-javascript-4f1323f96252

Comment: Well don’t assign oranges to apples, assign the same thing to the same thing: `document.getElementById('display-here').innerHTML = someAvatar.innerHTML`

Comment: @04FS This will work but will also kill any event handlers

Comment: @Andreas good point. Depends on what exactly is needed, question is rather fuzzy in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `cloneNode`
More info here: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp)

```js
let someAvatar = document.getElementsByClassName("avatar").item(0)
console.log(someAvatar);
var clonedElem = someAvatar.cloneNode(true);
document.getElementById("display-here").appendChild(clonedElem);
```

```html
<div class="avatars">
  <div class="avatar">
    <div>
      <svg data-jdenticon-value="Oamar Kanji"></svg>
    </div>
    <h3 class="name">Oamar Kanji</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="avatar">
    <div>
      <svg data-jdenticon-value="Oamar Kanji"></svg>
    </div>
    <h3 class="name">Jane Doe</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="display-here">
</div>
```

Comment: `.cloneNode()` is only necessary if TO needs a copy of the avatar.

Comment: @Andreas sorry for my question. what do you mean by TO?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following line inside script:

```
let someAvatar = document.getElementsByClassName("avatar").item(0).innerHTML;
```

instead of

> let someAvatar = document.getElementsByClassName("avatar").item(0)

Now someAvatar will have the HTML content inside of the div. Previously your were having the whole div HTML node.